# Could have escaped VS Couldn't have escaped

Tags: modal-verbs, perfect-constructions

I am stuck with perfect infinitive:

***I could have done = I had a posisibility to do but I didn't***

Then conversely it should mean

***I couldn't have done = I didn't have a posisibility to do but I did it (somehow)***

There are fugitives. Having escaped from a prison they are walking along a beach talking:

*A: Yeah, we are finally free. By the way, why didn't you kill that guard near the gates?*

*B: Then we **couldn't have escaped**.*

*A: Got it. I was so scaried when they freed the dogs! Thought it would be our end.*

*B: Nah, we'd already been far away. Even if they had called all helicopters they had, we **could have escaped**.*

There are fugitives. They are caught and returned to their cells. They are talking:

*A: Shit! +20 years to my 180 years! Now I definitely won't wait up till my discharge! Why didn't you kill that guard near the gates?*

*B: It wouldn't have helped us. We **couldn't have escaped**. We were shot 74 times.*

*A: Yeah, I probably didn't have to offer him 20 bucks for opening the gates when we would run.*

*B: God, again!? It's been the third time you tell some guard about our escape before escaping! This time we **could have escaped**! You're a trustful idiot!*

As I can see, the choice between **could have + V3** - **could not have + V3** doesn't really affect the reality. If we say **"could have + V3"** we don't know whether it really didn't happen or happened all the same. If we say **"could have not + V3"** - the same, we don't know if it occured or no. C-O-N-T-E-X-T. Right?

Comment: Michael, it would help if you were able to cut your question down to the bare minimum. (Your argument - the converse of **could have** is flawed. )

Comment: _I couldn't have done_ does NOT imply 'but I did somehow'. It would be more idiomatic to use different verb forms - "We wouldn't have been able to escape." "We could still have escaped"(?? Not sure of B's meaning.) etc.

Comment: I meant that when we say "I could have done" it probably means that in reality we don't have a result of having done it. So this phrase means "I could have done but in reality I haven't". And, I thought, conversely it would be the same: "I couldn't have done" probably means that in real life we have gotten the result of having done it. This way "I couldn't have done it" = I have done. Something like this...